# Встраивание видео с Youtube на сайт Тильда

Tags: share

Хочу встраивать свои видео ролики  с ютюба на сайт Тильда. При этом нужно отключить возможность пользователям поделиться этим видео или перейти для просмотра на сайт ютюб. Подскажите, как это сделать? Есть возможность встраивать htlm код или по прямой ссылке.